# Is there a way to assign the html from a razor page to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, razor-pages, modularity

I have a Razor page with 4 text boxes and a button that creates an additional text box below the other boxes.

When the user clicks the button, a javascript function addNewSection() is triggered and the new text section is inserted to the page.

```
function addNewSection() {
    var section = document.getElementById("lastTextBox");
    var newSection = `<div> razor page content here. </div>`
    section.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newSection);
    
}
```

This function works when I directly write my razor page content into var newSection. However, the actual razor page content is kind of long. Is there a neater way to do this?

I tried putting the page content into a new razor page "Section.cshtml" and setting var newSection equal to that (see below). But I'm getting an error "CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation". Any idea how I can do something similar to this? I would rather not put a whole cshtml page into my js function. Thanks!

```
var newSection = @RenderPage("~/Views/Section.cshtml);
```

Comment: Did you try putting the RenderPage call in quotes? `var new section = '@RenderPage(,...)';`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PartialAsync` HTML Helper:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var newSection = "@(await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Section.cshtml"))";
    </script>
}
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asynchronous-html-helper)

Comment: It would be better if you could provide an explanation.